# Power BI: Calculate the Maximum of an Average Value

Tags: powerbi

I have a table that depicts the turnover and uptime of a group of assets for a particular date range. It has the following columns:

Date, Asset_ID, Turnover, Uptime, Turnover/Uptime

What I have calculated in addition is the average Turnover/Uptime for the entire group of assets for a given date range. Every asset's Turnover/Uptime is then compared to that average to see how it performs relative  to other assets.

In addition I would like to calculate the following: The highest (thus the Maximum)  average Turnover/Uptime of any single asset for  the same period. With the goal of expressing each asset's turnover/uptime as a percentage of this maximum value.

I have not succeeded in this. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried quick measures? You could make an aggregate quick measure grouped by asset?

Comment: could you please specify?

Comment: I suggest you to provide a simple example and the expected output, otherwise how people could be able to help you?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear but if you are asking: how can I calculate the maximum of several averages, then here is my suggestion.
The pseudo-algorithm is the following:

1. Calculate the KPI at the level of granularity you need
2. Identify the maximum value

The KPI could be

```
MAX(AVERAGEX(ALL('Table'[Asset Key]), 'Table'[Turnover / Uptime]))
```